# Image name rewrite rule - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to add a rewrite rule to my htaccess file which will rewrite an image name based on what has been requested. For example:

```
<img src="www.site.com/img/intro-image.jpg">
```

The rule in turn should drop the 'intro-' and get/return image.jpg - or this is what I am trying to achieve.

My rewrite rule is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /img/(.*?)-(.*?).jpg /img/$2.jpg [L]
```

but this returns a 404?

Can anyone advise? TIA.

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you? Kindly do let me know on answer's comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img/(.*-)(.*\.jpg) img/$2 [NC,L]
```